# Compilation error - switch with enum

Tags: java, compiler-construction, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get an Enum constant reference cannot be qualified in a case label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663980/why-do-i-get-an-enum-constant-reference-cannot-be-qualified-in-a-case-label)

Hi,
Does someone knows why when I switch over an Enum, the cases should be on the unqualified Enum value?

Example:

```
switch(var) {

case Enum.FIRST:

break;

}
```

is illegal

but:

```
switch(var) {

case FIRST:

break;

}
```

is legal.

I understand that var is of a specific type (Enum) but why the compiler cares if I use the fully qualified name of the Enum value?

Comment: We miss the scope in which this takes place, as well as the Enum-definition, and the compiler error cited in full. Thank you.

Comment: @user unknown, the question is quite clear, I think

Comment: The difference is context. In the first case its the value in an corresponding instance (object). In second case its Class variable in Enum. Switch works on variable defined in instances used in switch clause. Its defined in spec that way.

Answer (score 9):

Because the Java Language Specification states that it is so.

Specifically, the defintition of a SwitchLabel:

```
SwitchLabel:
        case ConstantExpression :
        case EnumConstantName :
        default :
```

See http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#258896

Comment: I must say, I'm not very fund of "because thats just the way it is"-answers.

Comment: @aioobe Even when it's true? The reason the compiler behaves as it does is because that's how the language is defined. To find out WHY it's defined like that will need whoever wrote that part of the spec to come forward and say so.

Comment: Do you think that any part of the spec is written by a single person? and that this person is the only one knowing why he wrote as he did?

Comment: @aioobe At what point did I say it was a single person? "whoever" is (potentially) plural. Either way, someone involved in the process is what I was getting at.

Comment: I'm sure most reasons for why the language is designed as it is, can be read in the documentation, or at least deduced from it. See for instance the accepted answer to the duplicate question.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing because otherwise you could do something like this:

```
switch(var) {
  case AnyOtherEnum.FIRST:
  break;
}
```

Comment: But in case you do something like this, the compiler should raise an error. The compilers "knows" that the switch is on Enum and not AnyOtherEnum.

Comment: Yeah it knows. But the other way round, you can't even try to do the wrong thing

Comment: I guess you are right...

Comment: There's a better explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663980/why-do-i-get-an-enum-constant-reference-cannot-be-qualified-in-a-case-label

Answer (score 0):

Because you are switching 'var' already as "Enum", so the case Enum.FIRST would be "Enum.Enum.FIRST". Kind of ;-)

Comment: But the compiler "knows" it is a qualified Enum so it should not try to find "Enum.Enum.FIRST". I mean if the compiler sees a qualified enum in a case it could "understand" that.