# Switch on Enum in Java

Tags: java

Why can't you switch on an enum in Java? It seems simple enough to do and would make for some convenient code. Also this question could apply to `String`'s. You can switch on a `char`, but not a `String` ...?

Comment: Show us your non-working enum switch code.

Comment: Why duplicate flags, look at how precise is the heading, easy to find for new users.

Comment: You can take a look at this article to see how it's done: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/method_enum.htm

Comment: "It seems simple enough to do and would make for some convenient code." Yes Java is simple but convenient Java isn't! The REAL SIMPLE way of doing switch-statement is like it is in C and Java does it this way! On principle Java isn't convenient like C# is itended to. This is the Java way of life. You have to deal with this mentality if you realy want to code in Java.

Comment: You got this error because you are trying to type in the case enumName.Value
You have to type switch(enumVariable) {case value:}

Comment: Since Java 8 you can use Strings on a Switch statement.

Comment: FYI, this may get better in future versions of Java. See: [*JEP 406: Pattern Matching for switch (Preview)*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/406).

Answer (score 292):

You definitely can switch on enums. An example posted from the [Java tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

```
public enum Day {
    SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, 
    THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY 
}

public class EnumTest {
    Day day;

    public EnumTest(Day day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public void tellItLikeItIs() {

        switch (day) {
            case MONDAY: 
                System.out.println("Mondays are bad.");
                break;

            case FRIDAY: 
                System.out.println("Fridays are better.");
                break;

            case SATURDAY:
            case SUNDAY: 
                System.out.println("Weekends are best.");
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Midweek days are so-so.");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Beautiful example that answers the question very well.  That said, I've been programming Java for 14 years and I don't remember a single case where I kept a switch statement in production code.  When a switch statement would be better than a series of if/else, I have always written an instance method on my enum instead along the lines of what Josh Bloch suggests.  In my `Day` enum, I add `public string tellItLikeItis() { return "Midweek days are so-so."; }` then have `MONDAY`, `FRIDAY`, `SATURDAY`, and `SUNDAY` override that method.

Comment: Which is to say that I do it as @GregMattes suggests in the second-most-popular answer.

Comment: @GlenPeterson FYI if you're trying to optimize for speed, the switch statement approach might be faster because it's just a table lookup in the bytecode. With your approach, you have to push a new function onto the stack. It's a micro-optimization, but if speed is super important it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: @GlenPeterson, that assumes you're compiling the enum code yourself, which is obviously not always the case.

Answer (score 90):

You actually can `switch` on `enum`s, but you can't `switch` on `String`s until Java 7. You might consider using polymorphic method dispatch with Java `enum`s rather than an explicit `switch`. Note that `enum`s are objects in Java, not just symbols for `int`s like they are in C/C++. You can have a method on an `enum` type, then instead of writing a `switch`, just call the method - one line of code: done!

```
enum MyEnum {
    SOME_ENUM_CONSTANT {
        @Override
        public void method() {
            System.out.println("first enum constant behavior!");
        }
    },
    ANOTHER_ENUM_CONSTANT {
        @Override
        public void method() {
            System.out.println("second enum constant behavior!");
        }
    }; // note the semi-colon after the final constant, not just a comma!
    public abstract void method(); // could also be in an interface that MyEnum implements
}

void aMethodSomewhere(final MyEnum e) {
    doSomeStuff();
    e.method(); // here is where the switch would be, now it's one line of code!
    doSomeOtherStuff();
}
```

Comment: One of the nice things about this approach is that it is simply impossible to get certain types of errors. You can't miss a switch case (you can incorrectly implement a method for a particular constant, but there's nothing that will ever totally prevent that from happening!). There's no switch "default" to worry about. Also, I've seen code that puts enum constants into arrays and then indexes into the arrays - this opens the possibility of array index out of bounds exceptions - just use the enum! Java enums are very, very powerful. Learn all that you can about them to use them effectively.

Comment: Also note if you have several enum constants that all have the same behavior for a particular method (like @CoolBeans days of the week example in which weekend days have the same behavior and the weekdays Tuesday through Thursday also share the same behavior), you can simply gather that shared code in an enum method that is not overridden by every constant (final protected) and then call that method from the appropriate methods. So, in my example I could add "final protected void commonMethod() { ... }" and then the implementation of method() in each constant would just call commonMethod().

Comment: Now that this question has been closed as a duplicate, I notice that one of the duplicates has an answer quite (perhaps eerily) similar to mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663980/why-do-i-get-an-enum-constant-reference-cannot-be-qualified-in-a-case-label/2667671#2667671 - Scout's honor: I didn't know about his answer before I wrote mine!

Comment: :-). This question ended up being a _train-wreck_.

Comment: Why? Because it's a duplicate? It happens, no big deal. Maybe the information will be merged someday. You learned something, right? Somebody else probably did too. That alone makes it valuable.

Answer (score 27):

Article on Programming.Guide: [Switch on enum](https://programming.guide/java/switch-on-enum.html)

---

```
enum MyEnum { CONST_ONE, CONST_TWO }

class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            MyEnum e = MyEnum.CONST_ONE;

            switch (e) {
                case CONST_ONE: System.out.println(1); break;
                case CONST_TWO: System.out.println(2); break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Switches for strings are implemented in Java 7.

Answer (score 26):

First, you can switch on an `enum` in Java. I'm guessing you intended to say you can’t, but you can. `char`s have a set range of values, so it's easy to compare. Strings can be anything.

A `switch` statement is usually implemented as a [jump table (branch table)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_table) in the underlying compilation, which is only possible with a finite set of values. C# *can* switch on strings, but it causes a performance decrease because a jump table cannot be used.

Java 7 and later supports [`String` switches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html) with the same characteristics.

Comment: A bit of a code example would've been helpful...

Answer (score 18):

You might be using the enums incorrectly in the switch cases. In comparison with the above example by CoolBeans.. you might be doing the following:

```
switch(day) {
    case Day.MONDAY:
        // Something..
        break;
    case Day.FRIDAY:
        // Something friday
        break;
}
```

Make sure that you use the actual enum values instead of EnumType.EnumValue

Eclipse points out this mistake though..

Comment: +1 However I found that when you assign, you must use day = Day.Monday; Otherwise I was getting a 'cannot find symbol' compile error.

Comment: When you *assign* the value you have to use a qualified access like `day = Day.Monday;` (or use an `import static …`), however in case of `switch`, the `case` labels must use simple names, i.e. `switch(day) { case MONDAY: … break; case FRIDAY: … break; }`

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can use a switch statement with Strings in Java...unfortunately this is a new feature of Java 7, and most people are not using Java 7 yet because it's so new.