# Failure to initialize GregorianCalendar Object

Tags: java, date, calendar

I'm a complete beginner with Java, and I've been making simple test-programs to review some of the material I read. The following block of code works incorrectly. It's supposed to accept a Year, Month, and Date from the user, and then create a GregorianCalendar object initialized with the year, month and date. However, when I try to return the GregorianCalendar variable's month, it always gives back the month I initialized the month variable with. I'm not sure why.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Prac {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Year: ");
    int YEAR = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter Month: ");
    String MONTH_STRING = input.next();
    System.out.print("Enter Date: ");
    int DATE = input.nextInt();
    int MONTH = 10;
    String mon = MONTH_STRING.toLowerCase();

    if (mon == "january") {
        MONTH = 0;
    } else if (mon == "february") {
        MONTH = 1;
    } else if (mon == "march") {
        MONTH = 2;
    } else if (mon == "april") {
        MONTH =3;
    } else if (mon == "may"){
        MONTH =4;
    } else if (mon == "june"){
        MONTH =5;
    } else if (mon == "july"){
        MONTH =6;
    } else if (mon == "august"){
        MONTH=7;
    } else if (mon == "september"){
        MONTH=8;
    } else if (mon == "october"){
        MONTH=9;
    } else if (mon == "november"){
        MONTH=10;
    } else if (mon == "december"){
        MONTH =11;
    }

    GregorianCalendar entDate = new GregorianCalendar(YEAR,MONTH,DATE);
    System.out.println(entDate.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    }
}
```

Also, I'm aware I could have used a switch block,  but it gave me strange errors somehow.

Comment: Search for "string equality in Java". `mon == "january"` does not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 2):

## `String.equals`

You're comparing Strings incorrectly.

The `==` operator checks to see if the Objects are the same -- meaning same memory location and everything.

What you want to do is the [`String::equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) method.

```
if(mon.equals("january") {
    ...
} else if(mon.equals("feburary") {
    ...
} ...
```

This will check only to see if the value of the string is equal.

Also, unless you're using java 1.7+ you wouldn't be able to use a switch case for Strings. Not really a part of the question, but still good to know.

Comment: Ahh, I should have known. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Also, you might want to use the constants defined in Calendar for the months, instead of hard-coded integer values (Calendar.JANUARY, etc.).

Comment: @FrankPavageau Good call, months always trip me up with their zero relativity. :D

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by Shaded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12288708/642706) is correct and should be accepted. You should generally avoid using `==` comparison with objects, and instead call a method such as `equals` or `isEqual`.

Furthermore, you could call `String::equalsIgnoreCase` method rather than changing the string to be lowercase.

```
boolean sameIgnoringCase = thisString.equalsIgnoreCase( thatString ) ;
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the modern *java.time* classes.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (1986 means year 1986). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Compare months by using the `Month` enum rather than mere numbers or text. That class offers a dozen instances, one for each month of the year.

```
Month month = ld.getMonth() ;  // Get `Month` enum object.
```

You can [`switch` on an enum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6391777/642706).

```
switch( month ) {
    case JANUARY: 
        …
    case FEBRUARY: 
        …
    default:
        …
}
```

Note that a quirk in Java means you cannot prefix the `JANUARY` with `Month` (that is, `Month.JANUARY`) inside a switch. As a habit, I routinely use the enum class name with the object name, except in a `switch` where it is forbidden.

Also, you may find the `EnumSet` and `EnumMap` handy.

```
Set< Month > winter = EnumSet.of( Month.DECEMBER , Month.JANUARY , Month.FEBRUARY ) ;
boolean isWinter = winter.contains( myLocalDate.getMonth() ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).