# Declaring Enum as Constant?

Tags: java, enums

I have several calls to `Enum` DogStatus in my code, like this:

```
if(DogStatus.SLEEPING){
    //do something
}
```

How can I set up a `constant` of the `Enum` in my class, so that I don't need to alter all of them each time I want to change the `if condition`?

E.g. something like:

```
constant statusToCheck = DogStatus.SLEEPING
```

Comment: Enum is using for checking the condition, so you must use `if` or `switch` to check which condition is going to satisfied.

Comment: with the `if` condition this might not be possible, but you could go with a [switch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391777/switch-on-enum-in-java)

Comment: No I mean can I do something similar to e.g. constant statusToCheck = DogStatus.SLEEPING ?

Comment: Do you mean `final DogStatus statusToCheck = DogStatus.SLEEPING;` ?

Comment: An enum definition already is a constant, are you sure you need yet another?

Comment: he wants to turn "statusToCheck" into a constant, @MarkRotteveel, not the enum itself.

Comment: By the way, as a constant itself, `statusToCheck` should be all uppercase by convention: `STATUS_TO_CHECK`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private final DogStatus statusToCheck = DogStatus.SLEEPING;
```

or, if `statusToCheck` is declared inside a method:

```
final DogStatus statusToCheck = DogStatus.SLEEPING;
```

Java enums are immutable object instances and can be referenced as any other objects.