# No enum constant found

Tags: java

I declared enum as an input to the switch statement since it doesn't allow `String` values.

`public enum names{VALUE1, VALUE2}`

I have a `List` of values `(VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3)`

```
for(int i=0; i<list.size();i++)
{
    names n=new names(list.get(i).trim());
    switch(n) {
        case VALUE1:
            System.out.println("1");
            break;
        case VALUE2:
            System.out.println("2");
            break:
        default:
            System.out.println("Nothing to print");
    }
}
```

While executing the above-mentioned code, I am getting `No Enum constant Class.data.VALUE3.` error. Please help me resolve this error.

Comment: I have a `List` of values `(VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3)` if these are of type data, what else did you expect?

Comment: `data` isn't a type you can switch over. You can only switch on integers, strings and enums. If you can write `new data(...)`, it's not one of those.

Comment: @AndyTurner as long as he uses something like: case data.VALUE1:, why not?

Comment: @Stultuske because `d` isn't an enum type if you can create an instance of it, it's not a string, and it's not an integer. You just can't switch on this. If it were `data d = /* some method returning a value from data */`, fine - but it's not that.

Comment: @AndyTurner you can switch over enums, as long as you do it correctly. just take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391777/switch-on-enum-in-java

Comment: @Stultuske for the third time: *it isn't an enum type if you can create an instance of it*.

Comment: it's not practical, but it is possible, yes, even for enum types.

Comment: @Orsu "as an input to the switch statement since it doesn't allow String values." which version of Java are you using? Switching on strings has been allowed since Java 7.

Comment: @Andy I am using java 7

Comment: @OrsuSuni then switching on strings is allowed. Why do you think you can't use it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use names.valueOf(), but it will throw an exception if the name is not found:

```
for(int i=0; i<list.size();i++)
{
    try {
        names n=names.valueOf(list.get(i).trim());
        switch(n) {
            case VALUE1:
                System.out.println("1");
                break;
            case VALUE2:
                System.out.println("2");
                break:
            default:
                System.out.println("Nothing to print");
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println("Nothing to print");
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you need a loop:

```
private static names find(String name) {
    for (names n: names.values()) {
        if (n.name().equals(name)) {
            return n;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

but you would need to check for null before the switch:

```
for(int i=0; i<list.size();i++)
{
    names n=find(list.get(i).trim());
    if (n != null) {
        switch(n) {
            case VALUE1:
                System.out.println("1");
                break;
            case VALUE2:
                System.out.println("2");
                break:
            default:
                System.out.println("Nothing to print");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Nothing to print");
    }
}
```