# Java:processing dates

Tags: java, list, date

I'm very new to Java. So please bear with me. I have 4 variables:

```
mode =  prior|later|value;(can have either of these 3 values)
occurrence = 2
day = Wednesday
eta = 14:00
```

I'm trying to implement a method which will return a list `date` which is based on following criteria:

case 1 : `(mode=prior,occurence=2,day=wednesday,eta=14:00)`

should return dates of first 2 wednesdays of the next month from current month.

output = [Wed Aug 01 14:00:00 2018, Wed Aug 08 14:00:00 2018]

case 2 : (`mode=later,occurence=2,day=wednesday,eta=14:00`)

should return dates of last 2 wednesdays of the next month from current month.

output = [Wed Aug 22 14:00:00 2018, Wed Aug 29 14:00:00 2018]

case 3 : `(mode=value,occurence=3,day=wednesday,eta=14:00)`

should return date of 3rd wednesday of the next month from current month.

```
output = [Wed Aug 15 14:00:00 2018, Wed Aug 29 14:00:00 2018]
```

This is what I've done so far,

```
public static List<Date> getDates(Calendar c, String mode, int occurrence, int dayNo, String eta) {
            List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
            switch(mode) {
            case "value": {
                String[] times = eta.split(":");
                c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayNo);  
                c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, occurrence);
                c.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JULY + 1); 
                c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2018);
                c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(times[0]));
                c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(times[1]));
                dates.add(c.getTime());
            }
            }
            return dates;
        }
```

Is there a better way of doing what I've done. Also can somebody please help me with implementing the cases 1 and 2 ?

Comment: Is not the output of first example incorrect? It should return first and second month's wednesday but both is August.

Comment: Actually no, i'm trying to get the FIRST 2 wednesdays of August. So result will be 1 and 8 only..

Comment: Okey I just missed it.

Comment: Thats ok. No problem...

Comment: One more question, do you want to calculate from date now, or from beginning of moth?

Comment: Beginning of the next month from current month. For eg:, current month is July, so I would like to calculate from beginning of august.

Comment: You are using terrible old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using terrible old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

In particular, the `Calendar` class (well, actually, `GregorianCalendar`) is replaced by [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

## Use types (classes)

Use smart objects rather than dumb strings, where feasible. Using appropriate types makes your code more self-documenting, ensures valid values, provides for [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety), and lets the compiler catch your [typos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographical_error).

In your case, Java already provides types for most of your data. You can make your own type for the “mode”.

The [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) facility in Java is much more powerful and flexible than typically seen in other languages. See [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) to learn more. But the basics are simple, as seen here:

```
public enum Mode {
    PRIOR ,
    LATER ,
    VALUE
}
```

For day-of-week, use the [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum, pre-defining seven objects, one for each day of the week. For example, `DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY`.

For time-of-day, use [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html).

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 14 , 0 ) ;
```

For the current month, use [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class.

Determining the current year-month means determining the current date. Determining the current date requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ; // Or "America/Chicago", etc.
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.now( z ) ;
```

If you have a `LocalDate`, you can determine the year-month for it.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.from( myLocalDate ) ;
```

I suggest having the calling method determine the [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) rather than make this method jump through extra hoops. A general design approach in [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) is to separate, or disentangle, responsibilities. This method we are writing should be concerned with its own needs (a year-month value) and should not have to care about how the calling method arrives at its desired year-month whether that be from current date or current month or last month, etc.

Lastly, if your goal is to get a moment in time (a date with a time-of-day), then you must also specify a time zone. A date+time without the context of a time zone (or offset-from-UTC) has no real meaning.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

So, putting this all together, your method signature could look like this:

```
public static List< ZonedDateTime > getDates( 
    YearMonth ym , 
    Mode mode , 
    int occurrences , 
    DayOfWeek dow , 
    LocalTime lt ,
    ZoneId z
) { …
```

## Logic

The solution to your first two cases, `Mode.PRIOR` and `Mode.LATER`, is the use of the [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) interface. Specifically, the implementations found in [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) class can determine the “nth” weekday-of-month such as first Wednesday. Even more specifically:

- [`firstInMonth​( DayOfWeek dayOfWeek )`](http://irstInMonth%E2%80%8B(DayOfWeek%20dayOfWeek))
- [`lastInMonth​( DayOfWeek dayOfWeek )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#lastInMonth(java.time.DayOfWeek))

The main idea here is to start with the first (or last) day-of-week in the month. Then work our way down (up) through the month, week-by-week, adding (subtracting) a week at a time. Repeat for our limit of integer `occurrences`.

We can do a `switch` on our `Mode` enum, as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6391777/642706). Minor point: I would prefer to use `Mode.PRIOR` syntax rather than just `PRIOR`, for clarity. However, an obscure technicality in Java forbids that syntax in a `switch`. So, `case PRIOR:` not `case Mode.PRIOR:`, as shown further down in sample code.

We collect our resulting `ZonedDateTime` objects in a `List` named `moments`.

```
int initialCapacity = 5; // Max five weeks in any month.
List< ZonedDateTime > moments = new ArrayList<>( initialCapacity );
```

Let’s look at the logic for each of our three modes.

### `Mode.PRIOR`

Get the first day-of-week of the month.

```
    LocalDate firstDowOfMonth = ym.atDay( 1 ).with( TemporalAdjusters.firstInMonth( dow ) );
```

Work our way down through the month, adding a week at a time.

We might exceed the bounds of the month, going into the following month. So check the `YearMonth` to see if it is the same as when when started.

```
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < occurrences ; i++ ) {
        LocalDate ld = firstDowOfMonth.plusWeeks( i );
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z );
        if ( YearMonth.from( zdt ).equals( ym ) ) {  // If in same month…
            moments.add( zdt );
        }
    }
```

### `Mode.LATER`

This case uses the same logic as above, except we start at the bottom of the month and work our way up. Get the last day-of-week of month, then subtract a week at a time.

```
        // Start with last day-of-week in month.
        LocalDate lastDowOfMonth = ym.atDay( 1 ).with( TemporalAdjusters.lastInMonth( dow ) );
        // Work our way up through the month, subtracting a week at a time.
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < occurrences ; i++ ) {
            LocalDate ld = lastDowOfMonth.minusWeeks( i );
            ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z );
            if ( YearMonth.from( zdt ).equals( ym ) ) {  // If in same month…
                moments.add( zdt );
            }
        }
```

Because we are going backwards through time, our collection of `moments` is in reverse chronological order. So, we need to sort to present these in chronological order.

```
        Collections.sort( moments ); // If you want the list to be in chronological order, sort.  Otherwise in reverse chronological order for this `Mode.LATER`.
```

### `Mode.VALUE`

The last case is the simplest: Get the nth day-of-week in the month. That is simply a one-liner.

```
        LocalDate nthDowInMonth = ym.atDay( 1 ).with( TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth( occurrences , dow ) );
```

Do the usual, make a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( nthDowInMonth , lt , z );
```

Verify the month, as the documentation seems to be saying that exceeding the limits of the month takes us into the next month. In such a case, our logic omits the date from our list. So we will be returning `moments` as an empty list. This means the calling method should check for the list having elements, as it may be empty.

```
        if ( YearMonth.from( zdt ).equals( ym ) ) {  // If in same month…
            moments.add( zdt );
        }
```

Let’s see all the code put together.

```
// Simulate arguments passed.
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 14 , 0 );
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ); // Or "America/Chicago", etc.
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.now( z );
DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY;
Mode mode = Mode.PRIOR ;  // Mode.PRIOR, Mode.LATER, Mode.VALUE.
int occurrences = 3; // TODO: Add code to verify this value is in range of 1-5, not zero, not >5.

// Logic
int initialCapacity = 5; // Max five weeks in any month.
List< ZonedDateTime > moments = new ArrayList<>( initialCapacity );
switch ( mode ) {
    case PRIOR:
        // Start with first day-of-week in month.
        LocalDate firstDowOfMonth = ym.atDay( 1 ).with( TemporalAdjusters.firstInMonth( dow ) );
        // Work our way down through the month, adding a week at a time.
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < occurrences ; i++ ) {
            LocalDate ld = firstDowOfMonth.plusWeeks( i );
            ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z );
            if ( YearMonth.from( zdt ).equals( ym ) ) {  // If in same month…
                moments.add( zdt );
            }
        }
        break;

    case LATER:
        // Start with last day-of-week in month.
        LocalDate lastDowOfMonth = ym.atDay( 1 ).with( TemporalAdjusters.lastInMonth( dow ) );
        // Work our way up through the month, subtracting a week at a time.
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < occurrences ; i++ ) {
            LocalDate ld = lastDowOfMonth.minusWeeks( i );
            ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z );
            if ( YearMonth.from( zdt ).equals( ym ) ) {  // If in same month…
                moments.add( zdt );
            }
        }
        Collections.sort( moments ); // If you want the list to be in chronological order, sort.  Otherwise in reverse chronological order for this `Mode.LATER`.
        break;

    case VALUE:
        // Get the nth day-of-week in month.
        LocalDate nthDowInMonth = ym.atDay( 1 ).with( TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth( occurrences , dow ) );
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( nthDowInMonth , lt , z );
        if ( YearMonth.from( zdt ).equals( ym ) ) {  // If in same month…
            moments.add( zdt );
        }
        break;

    default:  // Defensive programming, testing for unexpected values.
        System.out.println( "ERROR - should not be able to reach this point. Unexpected `Mode` enum value." );
        break;
}
// return `moments` list from your method.
System.out.println( "moments:\n" + moments );
```

Note that the specified time-of-day on a particular date in our specified time zone may not be valid. For example, during a cutover in Daylight Saving Time (DST). If so, the `ZonedDateTime` class adjusts as needed. Be sure to read the documentation to make sure you understand and agree to its adjustment algorithm.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

So as I understand your question I wrote some code for example. I could not understand the "value" option. Desired output and explanation of method is not obvious for me. If you explain it I could edit the answer.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String s : findOccurence("prior", DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY, 2, "14:00")){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    public static String[] findOccurence(String mode, DayOfWeek day, int occurrence, String eta) {
        LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(now.getYear(), now.getMonth().plus(1), 1);
        LocalDate finish = start.plusDays(start.lengthOfMonth());

        List<LocalDate> dates = Stream.iterate(start, date -> date.plusDays(1))
                .limit(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, finish))
                .filter(d -> d.getDayOfWeek() == day)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        String[] formattedEta = eta.split(":");

        if (occurrence > dates.size()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }

        if (mode.equalsIgnoreCase("value")) {

        }
        else if (mode.equalsIgnoreCase("later")) {
            dates = Lists.reverse(dates);
        }

        //later and prior shares common logic

        return dates.stream()
                .limit(occurrence)
                .map(d -> day.toString()
                            + " "
                            + start.getMonth().name()
                            + " "
                            + d.getDayOfMonth()
                            + " "
                            + LocalTime.of(Integer.valueOf(formattedEta[0]), Integer.valueOf(formattedEta[1]), 0)
                            + " "
                            + start.getYear())
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .toArray(new String[occurrence]);
    }
}
```

Output is :

```
WEDNESDAY AUGUST 1 14:00 2018
WEDNESDAY AUGUST 8 14:00 2018
```