# error: an enum switch case label must be the unqualified name of an enumeration constant case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC

Tags: java

So I'm still a beginner at programming and Java. There is an upcoming project in a company where I currently am as a High School Intern. Part of that project is reading excel files and storing the data in variables to be used later.

To learn more about file reading and writing, I tried codes that I found on the internet to implement once and then go over them to understand what is going on in there. The problem is, most codes online show multiple Syntax errors and just straight up don't work. There isn't any real step by step guide that explains what exactly is required for reading Excel files and how to write a code for that.

[Since i'm too dumb to figure out the formatting on this site, here is an image of part of the code that gives problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QN2jF.png)

Apparently there seems to be no Syntax issue other than the unqualified enum. I'm using NetBeans IDE and it only highlights these three:

> 1) Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC: error: an enum switch case label must be
>   the unqualified name of an enumeration constant case
>   Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC
>
> 2) Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:error: an enum switch case label must be the
>   unqualified name of an enumeration constant case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING
>
> 3) Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:error: an enum switch case label must be the
>   unqualified name of an enumeration constant case
>   Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN

Comment: Dont make pictures of Code...

Comment: *Unqualified* means, you don't have to explicitly write the type before the `enum` values or class constants. First thing I've seen in your image (!) of code is `switch (Cell.getCellType())`, which should be `switch (cell.getCellType())` and then just write the `cases` without explicit qualification `Cell.`, just `case CELL_TYPE_SOMETHING: doIt(); break;`...

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to see how to format code. You can also use triple-backticks rather than indentation now, e.g. https://gist.github.com/jskeet/70b7e6884f9485c2f36f1d5bbd904df0

Comment: On entering code: an indented block (4 spaces) with empty lines above and below make code.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I tried formatting both ways, it still wouldn't accept.

Comment: What do you mean by "it still wouldn't accept"? What *exactly* happened? It's important to learn how to format code in order to be successful on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I figured out the indents, there was incorrect spacing at the beginning. I tried it again with a code and its accepting it now. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`case` in a switch case doesn't accept the Enum type (as it's automatically written by the compiler) :

```java
switch(cell.getType()) {
  case CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
  // will compile as case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC
    //doSomething()
    break;
  default:
    //doSomething()
}
```

Follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391777/switch-on-enum-in-java) as a tutorial