# Best way to handle Function Parameter with defined "States" in Java

Tags: java, methods, parameters

I would like to implement a Method with a input, which can be "A", "B" or "C". I know how to implement this with a String check, but I don't think its as clean as I need it to be. Is there any way doing this better (With an enum or something like that)?

Example:

```
private final options = {"A", "B", "C"};
private option;

public void setOption(option o){
   if(this.options.contains(o)){
      this.option = o;
   } else {
      this.option = null;
   }
}
```

Comment: I would do it with switch

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6391791/14002590 something like this

Comment: You say _"With an enum or something like that"_ - I say: Yes, with an enum!

Comment: Thanks guys, worked perfekt for me

Answer (score 0):

Use an Enum in combination with a switch statement.
If you need to futher process your string, use `String.equals(String)` to compare your two strings.