# I need a way to store a deck of cards into an array without hard coding them

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, card, playing-cards

The real problem is trying to create and store the Card objects in my array.
If i just needed to store strings or doubles for example i would be able to figure it out.
Im pretty new at this and this is my first stack overflow question so bear with me.
It might be worth noting i will eventually need to randomly generate random ints to pass through my card objects to get random cards.

This is my card class,

```
public class Card
{   
    private int value;
    private int suit;
    private String valueN;    
    private String valueS;
    Card(int value, int suit)
{
        this.value = value;
        this.suit = suit;
}   
    public String valueNumber()
{    
    switch(value)
{
      case 1:
              valueN = "Ace";
              break;
      case 2:
              valueN = "Two";
              break;
      case 3:
              valueN = "Three";
              break;
      case 4:
              valueN = "Four";
              break;
      case 5:
              valueN = "Five";
              break;
      case 6:
              valueN = "Six";
              break;
      case 7:
              valueN = "Seven";
              break;
      case 8:
              valueN = "Eight";
              break;
      case 9: 
              valueN = "Nine";
              break;
      case 10:
              valueN = "Ten"; 
              break;
      case 11:
              valueN = "Jack";
              break;
      case 12:
              valueN = "Queen";
              break;
      case 13:
              valueN = "King"; 
              break;
}      
        return valueN;
    }
    public String suitNumber()
{
    switch(suit)
{    
      case 1: 
              valueS = "Hearts";
              break;
      case 2:
              valueS = "Clubs";
              break;
      case 3:       
              valueS = "Spades";
              break;        
      case 4:        
              valueS = "Diamonds";
}                    
        return valueS;
}  
    public String getValueN() 
{
    return this.valueN;
}
   public String getSuitS()
{
    return this.valueS;
}
  public int getValue()
{
    return this.value;
}
  public int getSuit()
{
    return this.suit;
}
   public String toString() 
{
        return valueNumber() + " of " + suitNumber();       
}
}
```

Do i need to use those accessor methods?
Ive been trying to solve this for an embarrassing amount of time and still dont know if i should use a regular array or a 2d array or something new altogether.

I should mention this is for a school assignment and i dont know if stack overflow has anything asking questions pertaining to assignments but i assure you this is a very small part of this assignment.

This is my deck class and my best attempt at creating the loop and array i need but it gets out of bounds exception error and is probably wrong.

```
public class Deck
{
    Deck ()
    {
        int index = 0;
        Card deck [] = new Card [51]; 
            
            for (int value = 1; value <= 13; value++)
            {
                for (int suit = 0; suit <= 3; suit++)
                {
                  deck[index] = new Card (value, suit);
                  index++;
                }           
            }

    
    }   
}
```

I feel as though i need to make use and perhaps modify my accessor methods from my card class in my Deck constructor.

Comment: That's not too bad. As it happens, you can model playing cards as `enum`s. In fact there is an 'official' tutorial showing just that. You could improve it a bit by using more self-documenting names for `getValueN` and `getValueS`- I read them and didn't know *immediately* what they did.

Comment: Your deck lacks one element btw: `[x]` means that it has x elements. It is *indexed* 0 thru x-1. [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/examples/Deck3.java) is how easy it is to write a deck class with the cards having `enum`s

Comment: i dont believe i can use an enum here because i am forced to use switch statements @g00se

Comment: I added an x variable to store all the new cards and everything works now thank you very very much for the suggestion @g00se

Comment: Actually I was just making a general point with the 'x' thing. You don't need a variable. Though you could define and use a constant such as `DEFAULT_DECK_SIZE`

Comment: _i dont believe i can use an enum here because i am forced to use switch statements_: did you know that you can use enum constants in a switch statement? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391777/switch-on-enum-in-java - or from the Java Tutorials: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: You have an "off by one" error. Your "value" `switch` goes from 1 to 13, and your "suits" `switch` goes from 1 to 4. In your `Deck` constructor, the outer `for` loop for "values" is correctly going from 1 to 13, but your inner `for` loop that is generating the "suits" is going from 0 to 3. So you need to either change the `switch` or the `for` loop...  =)

Comment: There are 52 cards in a deck. So this is wrong: `new Card [51];`. And a likely reason for your out of bounds exception. Your code looks fine to me.

Comment: By the way, "Ace" is usually, but not always, the card with the highest value. It would help if the names of your ranks were in value order: "Two", "Three", "Four", ... , "Queen", "King", "Ace".

Comment: An alternative to using switch / case in your ~Number methods is to use an array: `public String valueNumber () { final String [] rankName = {"Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five", ... , "King", "Ace"}; return rankName [value];}`