# More descriptive Collection<String> in Java

Tags: java, generics, collections

Suppose I have a class `SalesOrder` that is widely used in my project.  One of the member fields is `String orderType`.

At various points in my processing, I need to maintain a `Map` of order type to `Integer` or maybe a `record`, to do things like keep track of how many orders of each type have been processed on a given day or whatever.

So, I have variables like

```
Map<String, Integer> orderTypeUnitCountMap = new HashMap<>();
```

I'd like my code to be more descriptive, to make clear the intention that the key value in the map should be an order type.  Something like:

```
Map<OrderType, Integer> orderTypeUnitCountMap = new HashMap<>();
```

But I don't have an `OrderType` class, since the only thing I know about the order type is its name (which is the value in the string).

It there an easy, common way to define collections of basic objects like `String` or `Integer` in a way that the intention / domains are clearer?  I'm thinking/hoping for a recently introduced language feature I'm not yet familiar with?

Comment: It depends on what you mean.  Enums play in this space, but I suspect you're looking for something more dynamic, and I don't think Java has that.  Not as a *bona fide* data type.

Comment: Create a simple wrapper: `record OrderType(String name) {}`

Comment: I was also going to suggest a domain object that just wraps the string (or whatever info you need).  Or you could encapsulate the map, hiding the implementation behind method calls: `int getCount( OrderType o )`

Comment: You could also include the `Map` as a `private static field` in the `SalesOrder` class.  This would be shared among all instances and could be incremented for the type of order when the object is created.  When retrieved via a getter, a defenseive copy of the map should be returned so it can't be modified outside the instance. This should, imo, negate the need for  anything other than a comment for the maps contents.

Comment: @shmosel I guess that'll probably be the best way.  If you want to write a short answer, I'll upvote/accept.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If the order types are known at compile-time, then an enum type would be the obvious choice. Otherwise you could simply define a OrderType class that wraps a String name.

A third option could be a combination of the two. This might be useful if some order types are known at compile time but others are dynamic, e.g.:

```java
public interface OrderType {
    static OrderType valueOf(String name) {
        return OrderTypeRegistry.valueOf(name);
    }

    String name();

    enum OrderTypeEnum implements OrderType {
        ORDER_TYPE_A,
        ORDER_TYPE_B
    }

    record OrderTypeName(String name) implements OrderType {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }
}

class OrderTypeRegistry {
    private static final Map<String, OrderType> nameValueMap = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        for (OrderType.OrderTypeEnum orderType : OrderType.OrderTypeEnum.values()) {
            nameValueMap.put(orderType.name(), orderType);
        }
    }

    static OrderType valueOf(String name) {
        return nameValueMap.computeIfAbsent(name, OrderType.OrderTypeName::new);
    }
}
```

Comment: In up-to-date Java versions, you can add `sealed` to the declaration, `public sealed interface OrderType { …` to restrict implementations to the two classes. Keep in mind that nested types of interfaces are implicitly `public`, so code from the outside still can create new instances of `OrderTypeName`.

Answer (score 0):

## Enum

When designing your app, you should flush out what exactly are the types of sales orders. These values are part of your [domain model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model).

In Java, you would represent those possible types of sales orders as predefined, named objects declared as an [enum](https://www.baeldung.com/a-guide-to-java-enums).

```java
enum SalesOrderType { CASH_SALES , RUSH_ORDER , SCHEDULING_AGREEMENT }
```

Note how the class name is singular. And note the use of ALL_CAPS for the object names, as these are immutable [constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_(computer_programming)).

You would then use these enum objects as the keys of your `Map`. You would likely use [`EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.base/java/util/EnumMap.html) as the implementation, as it is extremely efficient with memory and CPU, being built expressly for enums as the key.

```
Map < SalesOrderType , Integer > countOfSalesOrdersTodayByType = new EnumMap<>() ;
```

Example usage:

```
countOfSalesOrdersTodayByType.put( SalesOrderType.RUSH_ORDER , 7 ) ;
```

Using enums ensures valid values, where as `String` use can be error-prone and difficult to debug.

You can `switch` on enum values. See Questions on [using enums with `switch`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6391777/642706). In Java 21+, your switch-on-enum can be exhaustive, per [*JEP 441: Pattern Matching for switch*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/441). Notice how in the next example, there is no need for a `default` case as all possible cases are covered — and enforced by the compiler!

```
switch ( someSalesOrderType ) {
    case CASH_SALES -> {
        … // do something
    }
    case RUSH_ORDER -> {
        … // do something else
    }
    case SCHEDULING_AGREEMENT -> {
        … // do different thing
    }
}
```

You said:

> since the only thing I know about the order type is its name (which is the value in the string).

Sounds like you or your stakeholders are conflating the sales order type with a name/description. Such confusion is common and normal as part of the analysis work in determining the full domain model.

Given that you posted this Question, I suspect you do have in mind a possible domain of knowable types of sales orders. The name/description should be kept separate, as text (`String`) probably.

---

Tip: Enum declaration can now be local, within a method. Ditto for interface and record definition. See [*JEP 395: Records*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395).

Comment: Thanks, but an `enum` won't work for me.  There are a limited set of order types, true, but they are defined in a separate application and stored in a database.  It'd not be acceptable to have to update and redeploy our application whenever there is a new order type defined.